# Start process in background quietly

Tags: bash, fork

Appending a `&` to the end of a command starts it in the background. E.g.:

```
$ wget google.com &
[1] 7072
```

However, this prints a job number and PID. Is it possible to prevent these?

Note: I still want to keep the output of `wget` – it's just the `[1] 7072` that I want to get rid of.

Comment: **$> wget input & >NIL: ** sends output to bin ( deleted ).

Comment: @ArifBurhan This creates a file called `NIL`, doesn't suppress output to standard error, and the job number / PID message isn't generated by the command anyway, so this doesn't work.

Comment: What he meant was `wget google.com & >/dev/null`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, but it doesn't suppress the job control message either.

Comment: Your only alternative is to run it in a subshell and background from there. `( wget google.com & )`. That will kill the jobs output.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh, may I add that to my answer? With due credit, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to the `set` builtin, `set -b`, that controls the output of this line, but the choice is limited to "immediately" (when set) and "wait for next prompt" (when unset).

Example of immediate printing when the option is set:

```
$ set -b
$ sleep 1 &
[1] 9696
$ [1]+  Done                    sleep 1
```

And the usual behaviour, waiting for the next prompt:

```
$ set +b
$ sleep 1 &
[1] 840
$ # Press enter here
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1
```

So as far as I can see, these can't be suppressed. The good news is, though, that job control messages are not displayed in a non-interactive shell:

```
$ cat sleeptest
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1 &
$ ./sleeptest
$
```

So if you start a command in the background *in a subshell*, there won't be any messages. To do that in an interactive session, you can run your command in a subshell like this (thanks to [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin)):

```
$ ( sleep 1 & )
$
```

which also results in no job control prompts.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/zeros.html):

> Suppressing `stdout`.
>
> ```
> cat $filename >/dev/null
> # Contents of the file will not list to stdout.
> ```
>
> Suppressing `stderr` (from [Example
>   16-3](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/moreadv.html#EX57)).
>
> ```
> rm $badname 2>/dev/null
> #           So error messages [stderr] deep-sixed.
> Suppressing output from both stdout and stderr.
> cat $filename 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
> #1 If "$filename" does not exist, there will be no error message         output.
> # If "$filename" does exist, the contents of the file will not list to stdout.
> # Therefore, no output at all will result from the above line of code.
> #
> #  This can be useful in situations where the return code from a command
> #+ needs to be tested, but no output is desired.
> #
> # cat $filename &>/dev/null
> #     also works, as Baris Cicek points out.
> ```

Comment: I still want stdout/stderr as normal; it's just the job number and PID I don't want.